# How to set hover transition when the mouse gets out of the element

Tags: html, css

I set a hover transition for my button but as you can see when the mouse gets out of the button there is no animation like before what should I do to get transition for it?
thanks a lot.

```
#button{
background-color: #F69680;
border: 2px solid   #2e2263;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 10px 20px;
color:  #2e2263;
}

#button:hover{
    transition: 0.25s;
    background-color:  #2e2263 ;
    color:  #F69680;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better solution but you can set a transition on the `#button`, so if the button is not hovered anymore the `#button` is executed/drawn.